# How to check if a model has been changed but has not been saved to the server? (Ember.js / Ember-data)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

With ember models as they are changed by user input, they are persisted over the application with the changed values (until a refresh of some sort to reload the data from the server). Now  these models and their changes have not been saved to the server.

So I am wondering how I can check if models have been changed but have not been saved to the server yet.

Use case: To let users know that the following changes have not been saved yet.

I am just looking for some sort of boolean variable if one is available through ember or ember-data.

If not, some help would be appreciated to roll my own (I'm very new to ember).

Comment: Assign the model to a var on load, then when doing an event, check the value of the model against the initial variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [isDirty](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isDirty) attribute.

Comment: Seems like that's the one, i'll wait till I can accept your answer.